# Use dataframe with two level index as look up table to fill in values in another dataframe by nearest previous date

Tags: pandas

I want to use a look up table of events to populate a new index column in a dataset.

I have a data frame that holds a batchcode list indexed by date and tank. Where date is the date the batch was allocated. These dates change intermittently whenever fish are moved between tanks.

```
        batchcode
date    tank    
2016-01-02  LD  TRE-20160102-A-1
LA  TRE-20160102-B-1
2016-01-09  T8  TRE-20160109-C-1
LB  TRE-20160109-C-1
2016-01-25  LA  TRE-20160125-D-1
2016-01-27  LD  TRE-20160102-A-2
LC  TRE-20160102-A-3
2016-02-02  LD  TRE-20160102-E-1
LA  TRE-20160125-D-2
LB  TRE-20160109-C-2
```

I have a second table that lists daily activities such as feeding, temperature observations etc.

```
    Date    Tank    Property    Value   
0   2015-12-06  LC  Green Water (g) 50.0    
1   2015-12-07  LC  Green Water (g) 50.0    
2   2015-12-08  LC  Green Water (g) 50.0    
3   2015-12-09  LC  Green Water (g) 50.0    
4   2015-12-10  LC  Green Water (g) 50.0
```

I want to add a new column to this 2nd table for batchcode where the value the batchcode from the first table. i.e I need to match on Tank and for each date find the batchcode set for that date - that is at the most recent previous entry.

What is the best way to solve this?  My initial solution ends up running a function for every row of table 2 and this seems inefficient. I feel that I should be able to get table 1 to work as a simple indexed lookup
df2['batchcode'] = df1.find(df2['date', 'tank'], 'batchcode', method='pad')  # pseudocode

- Should I try to convert the tanks to columns?
- how do I find the nearest most recent date in the index.

loading code

```
bcr_file = f'data/batch_code_records.csv'
bcr_df = pd.read_csv(bcr_file, dtype='str')
bcr_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(bcr_df['change_date'])
bcr_df.drop(['unique_id', 'species', 'parent_indicator',
       'change_date', 'entered_by', 'fish_class', 'origin_parents_wild_breed',
       'change_reason_1', 'change_reason_2', 'batch_new', 'comments',
       'fish_count', 'source_population_or_wild', 'source_batch_1',
       'source_batch_2', 'batch_previous_1', 'batch_previous_2', 'tank_from_1',
       'tank_from_2'], axis=1, inplace=True)

bcr_df.set_index(['date', 'tank'], inplace=True)
```

Source data file

```
unique_id,batchcode,tank,species,parent_indicator,change_date,entered_by,fish_class,origin_parents_wild_breed,change_reason_1,change_reason_2,batch_new,comments,fish_count,source_population_or_wild,source_batch_1,source_batch_2,batch_previous_1,batch_previous_2,tank_from_1,tank_from_2
TRE-20160102-A-1-LD-20160102,TRE-20160102-A-1,LD,TRE,A,20160102,andrew.watkins@plantandfood.co.nz,WILD OLD,WILD,unstocked_source_to_empty_destination,,,"tank_move_comment: 26905 stock to LA, 26905 LA to LD",26905.0,WILD,,,,,,
TRE-20160102-B-1-LA-20160102,TRE-20160102-B-1,LA,TRE,B,20160102,andrew.watkins@plantandfood.co.nz,WILD OLD,WILD,new_from_wild,,,"tank_move_comment: 26905 stock to LA, 26905 LA to LD",26905.0,WILD,,,,,,
```

etc.

I tried using get_indexer but couldn't get it to work with the 2 level index, and with only date as the index I get non-unique date warnings.

Comment: can you provide the constructor of your input? The format is ambiguous

Comment: added the loading code and first few lines of source csv file. Thanks